# Center a XML created button with java

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity

is it possible to center a button that was created using XML using java?

I know they can be set to be not visible:

```
button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Basically, I have an if statement and I want it to do this:

```
If (possibility == true) {
     //center button horizontally and stay the same vertically
}
```

Comment: What is the buttons parent layout?  RelativeLayout?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you should be able to do something to this effect:

```
RelativeLayout.Layoutparams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)button.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.id_to_be_below);

button.setLayoutParams(params); //causes layout update
```

Relative layouts are sometimes funny so you might have to play around with these rules until you get it exactly how you want it, but this will get you on the right track!